# Why does this query return all the rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
SELECT 
    Credit_book_number, 
    (Last_name + ' ' + First_name + ' ' + Patronymic) AS [Name]
FROM 
    Student
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT Credit_book_number
            FROM GradeList g 
            GROUP BY Credit_book_number
            HAVING MIN(g.Grade) >= 6)
```

I want to get all the students who have a min grade 6, and I need to do it in subquery in where (most wanted to do it with exists, but not obligatory). My query right now returns all the students, however subquery gets not all of them.

Comment: Because a `Credit_book_number` (from your sub-query) does exists for all Students.

Comment: @Luuk is there a way out of this?

Comment: You haven't establish any "link" between the main (outer) query, and the subquery inside the `EXISTS` clause - so the `EXISTS` always checks the **entire** table, and if there is at least one match, it will always return **true** and thus the main, outer query returns all rows

Comment: @marc_s so I need only to establish a link?

Comment: The term of art for what you want is [correlated subquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15#correlated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If just one grade satisfies the condition, then this condition is true for all students, because you do not relate it to the current student.

Change it to

```sql
SELECT 
    Credit_book_number, 
    (Last_name + ' ' + First_name + ' ' + Patronymic) AS [Name]
FROM 
    Student
WHERE 
    Student.Credit_book_number IN (
            SELECT Credit_book_number
            FROM GradeList g 
            GROUP BY Credit_book_number
            HAVING MIN(g.Grade) >= 6)
```

Now, only students having a `Credit_book_number` with an according number in the `GradeList` satisfying the condition are selected.

Another way to make it work, is to add an additional WHERE clause to the sub-select to connect it to the student.

```sql
SELECT 
    Credit_book_number, 
    (Last_name + ' ' + First_name + ' ' + Patronymic) AS [Name]
FROM 
    Student
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1   -- It does not matter what we select here
            FROM GradeList g 
            WHERE g.Credit_book_number = Student.Credit_book_number
            GROUP BY Credit_book_number
            HAVING MIN(g.Grade) >= 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

could be you just need a group by with join avoding the exists

```
SELECT  s.Credit_book_number, 
    (s.Last_name + ' ' + s.First_name + ' ' + s.Patronymic) AS [Name]
FROM Student s 
INNER JOIN GradeList g on g.Credit_book_number = s.Credit_book_number
GROUP BY s.Credit_book_number  
having   HAVING MIN(g.Grade) >= 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to achieve this:

```
SELECT 
    Credit_book_number, 
    (Last_name + ' ' + First_name + ' ' + Patronymic) AS [Name]
FROM 
    Student
WHERE 
    Credit_book_number IN (SELECT Credit_book_number
            FROM GradeList g 
            GROUP BY Credit_book_number
            HAVING MIN(g.Grade) >= 6)
```